# How do I interpret this visitors user environment data

Tags: http-headers, environment-variables, user-agent

I have a client who experienced problems at our webapp. I have this from the session:

```
Browser:    Internet Explorer 9.0
Platform:   Microsoft Windows Vista
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0)
Language:   Danish (da-DK)
```

So he is using IE 9.0 on Vista, but whats with the Mozilla 5/0 in User Agent? And what is Trident/5.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately, during the browser wars, many web servers were configured to only send web pages that required advanced features to clients that were identified as some version of Mozilla.
>
> For this reason, most Web browsers use a User-Agent value as follows: Mozilla/[version] ([system and browser information]) [platform] ([platform details]) [extensions].
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

In other words, virtually all browsers identify themselves as some version of Mozilla to be more compatible with old, ignorant web servers and bad practices.

[Trident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29) is Internet Explorer's [rendering engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_layout_engines).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation: Do you know what the Windows NT 6.0 refer to, is this synonym for Windows Vista?

Comment: Yes, Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7 are all versions of and successors to Windows NT.

Answer (score 2):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx:

> Mozilla/5.0   Application name and version. For historical reasons, Internet Explorer identifies itself as a Mozilla browser
>
> Trident/5.0   The Trident token identifies the version of MSHTML (Trident) and can used to determine whether or not the webpage is displayed in Compatibility View.